# resize footer for mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a footer that I've made, but I can't figure out how to make the three images smaller and be vertically aligned for mobile. I want all 3 about 50% size and be in a vertical line.

The HTML is -

```
<div class="as-seen-footer">
  <div class="as-seen-items" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="as-featured">
      <h1 style="color: white; font-weight: lighter;">as featured in</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="verticalLine" style="padding-right: 20px;"></div>
    <div class="as-seen-images" style="display: flex;">
      <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5021" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/news_24_logo.svg" alt="Media 24" />
      <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5022" style="width: 150px; padding-right: 20px;" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/home_magazine_logo.svg" alt="Home Magazine" />
      <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5023" style="width: 100px; padding-right: 20px;" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/tuis_tydskrif_logo.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS for desktop is -

```
.as-featured h1 {
  font-size: 22px; 
}

.as-featured {
  padding-top: 12px; 
  padding-right: 20px; 
}

img.alignnone.size-full.wp-image-5021
{
  width: 150px; 
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.as-seen-items {
  display:flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.as-seen-images {
  display:flex;
}

.as-seen-footer {
  background: #000000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 130px;
}

.verticalLine {
  border-left: solid #fff;
  border-width: 2px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

I've tried the following media query, which resizes the text and vertical line, but I can't get the images to move and resize -

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px)
{
  .as-featured h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .as-featured {
    padding-top: 15px; 
  }

  img.alignnone.size-full.wp-image-5021 {
    width: 60%;
    display: inline;
  }

  .as-seen-footer {
    background: #000000;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .verticalLine {
    border-left: solid #fff;
    border-width: 2px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: what needs to happen to the vertical line when in mobile?

Comment: It just needs to be a bit smaller - the css in the media query seems to work.. it's just the images I can't get vertical and I can't make them smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `px` to specify width and height of your elements since it is not responsive. Use `vw` and `vh` which stand for `viewport` width and `viewport` height respectively instead. `vw` and  `vh` specify the size relative to the device size in which the website is being viewed  There is no need to use `@media` if use `vw` and `vh` to specify size.

Comment: okay.. what do I change? when I make some elements vw it messes everything up?

Comment: you can not just replace px to vw. you have to change the numbers too. 100vw means full width of the viewport. so for example if you want your element to have one tenth width of the view port you would give it a width of 10vw.

Comment: ohh it works... that's a great new trick I learnt! Thanks so much! :)